# Heat.exe (fro WiX library) not able to create task for SlowCheetah

Tags: msbuild, wix, slowcheetah

I am referencing my `.csproj` within an script of `heat.exe` to generate output `.wxs` files but it gets to this error.

> heat.exe : error HEAT5313 : Build error during harvesting: C:...\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v2.5.11\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets(160,5): The "SlowCheetah.Xdt.TransformXml" task could not be instantiated from the assembly "C:...\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v2.5.11\SlowCheetah.Xdt.dll". Please verify the task assembly has been built using the same version of the Microsoft.Build.Framework assembly as the one installed on your computer and that your host application is not missing a binding redirect for Microsoft.Build.Framework. Unable to cast object of type 'SlowCheetah.Xdt.TransformXml' to type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask'.
>   heat.exe : error HEAT5313 : Build error during harvesting: C:...\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v2.5.11\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets(160,5): The "SlowCheetah.Xdt.TransformXml" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.
>   heat.exe : error HEAT5307 : Build failed.

I have used `SlowCheetah` in my project for transformation of XML files.
It looks that `heat.exe` is going to do the same thing as `msbuild` does for transformation, but it failed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue? I am currently facing the same error.

Comment: No, actullay i ended up to just put away WIX altogether and just wait for the moment they provide some better process. I am sure that there is no way other that using head.exe  which really sucks!